# Object() takes no arguments

Tags: python-3.x

I get, "TypeError: Question() takes no arguments" (where Question is an object of class Question) when trying to execute the code below.

I'm using jupyter notebook and have checked most of my indentation, Tthe class Question has 2 attributes, I have an init method...

Issue is related to the function find_best_split(rows) below.

I have added an image of the error console output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYsQb.png)

```
    class Question:

    def __init__(self, column, value):
        self.column = column
        self.value = value


    def match(self, example):
        val = example[self.column]
        if is_numeric(val):
            return val >= self.value
        else:
            return val == self.value


    def __repr__(self):
        condition = "=="
        if is_numeric(self.value):
            condition = ">="
        return "Is %s %s %s?" % (header[self.column], condition, str(self.value))


    def partition(rows, question):

        true_rows, false_rows = [], []
        for row in rows:
            if question.match(row):
                true_rows.append(row)
            else:
                false_rows.append(row)
        return true_rows, false_rows
```

` Error points to this function, specifically "question = Question(col, val)"

```
    def find_best_split(rows):
        best_gain = 0
        best_question = None
        current_uncertainty = gini(rows)
        n_features = len(rows[0]) -1 # number of columns

        for col in range(n_features):
            values = set([row[col] for row in rows]) # unique values in the column
            for val in values: #now for each value
                question = Question(col, val)
                # trying to split the data set
                true_rows, false_rows = partition(rows, question)
                # skips this split if it doesn't divide the data set.
                if len(true_rows) == 0 or len(false_rows) == 0:
                    continue    
                # calculate the information gain from this split
                gain = info_gain(true_rows, false_rows, current_uncertainty)

                # you can use > instead of >= below but I wanted the data set to look a certain way for this example.
                if gain >= best_gain:
                    best_gain, best_question = gain, question
            return best_gain, best_quesiton
```

`

```
    class Decision_Node:

    def __init__(self, question, true_branch, false_branch):
            self.question = question
            self.true_branch = true_branch
            self.false_branch = false_branch



    def build_tree(rows):
        gain, question = find_best_split(rows)
        if gain == 0:
            return Leaf(rows)


        true_rows, false_rows = partition(rows, question)

        true_branch = build_tree(true_rows)

        false_branch = build_tree(false_rows)



        return Decision_Node(question, true_branch, false_branch)




    if __name__ == '__main__':   

        my_tree = build_tree(training_data)

        print_tree(my_tree)

        # Evaluate
        testing_data = [
            ["Green", 3, "Mango"],
            ["Yellow", 4, "Mango"],
            ["Red", 2, "Grape"],
            ["Red", 1, "Grape"],
            ["Yellow", 3, "Lemon"],
        ]

        for row in testing_data:
         print ("Actual: %s. Predicted: %s" % (row[-1], print_leaf(classify(row, my_tree))))
```

Comment: Where the code with the `Question` class in it.

Comment: Share the code of class Question and part of the code that is giving error. It will be more helpful.

Comment: *and have checked most of my indentation*... you should check **all** indentations. ;)

Comment: Please reduce your code to a *minimal* verifiable example. That is currently way too much information for people to dig through if all you need is help on one invocation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: too much code to read through. My assumption is that you have overwritten `question` that it's not a Question object any more.

Comment: There will be more problems with your code than you suggested within the post. What about this part of your code: best_question = None and then return best_gain, best_quesiton? Where best_quesiton comes from?

Comment: wow you guys are fast. Sorry but still editing it.

Comment: You're new to StackOverflow. So here are some info for you, because there are some issues within your question: 1. Please read carefully the [help site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and do your best to edit your question according to this **before** you post your question. 2. Your identations are still wrong. Edit your question and ensure that everything is ok. We can not assume for you how to ident your code, that's part of Python's logic. 3. Provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This includes that your code will work after copy/paste. This is not the case here.

Comment: Ok, So. On my way to producing a better MCVE I noticed Colidyre's comment about indenting a second time. I realized that 3 functions weren't indented following my class declaration "Question" hence were not recognized as methods of that class hence, resulted in the issue. Thank you Colidyre. Also thanking New2Python as he saw a further issue. Thankyou to all who commented too.